# On repeating adjectives

Tags: syntactic-analysis, repetition

Consider the following sentence:

> Oh you think this speech is insulting? Don't worry, it gets much more (*insulting*).

How should I phrase this sentence? Can I omit the second occurrence of the adjective or do I have to make a repetition?

I feel the sentence is unclear without it, but sounds stupid with it.

I don't have this problem with regular adjective, where the repetition feels more natural as the word is still different:

> Oh you think this is scary? Don't worry, it gets much scarier.

I thought of using

> don't worry, it gets much **worse**.

but I don't want to add a notion of good or bad. *Insulting* isn't the best example and without context you might want to use *much worse* but I'm sure there are adjective that don't have any good or bad connotation so it wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**More so**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/more_so) is used to indicate that an attribute or quality applies to a greater degree or extent. The phrase is not inherently positive or negative.

> Oh, you think this speech is insulting? Don't worry, it gets much **more so**.
>
> Oh, you think this speech is flattering? Don't worry, it gets much **more so**.